# Small webserver serving dynamic content

Tags: php, asp.net, python, windows, apache

Is there a small webserver for Windows that serves dynamic content (e.g. PHP, Python, Ruby, ASP.NET,...)?

I already tried Lighttpd, but it tends to be very slow with PHP.

The server should be small in memory-footprint, start at login and serve as the local browsers homepage. The ability to display dynamic content is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only meant for serving local user, then any development server that comes with web frameworks (such as [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) for python) should be ok. 
Some standalone servers (wsgi, for python):

- [waitress](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/)
- [rocket](http://packages.python.org/rocket/usage.html)

They'll probably be no help serving php or ruby, but the first part of my answer should apply there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tried [abyss](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/) yet?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) ?

Comment: Why is `nginx` the right choice? Include more than just a link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes only, php 5.4+ has a builtin webserver.

Besides nginx or abyss (mentioned earlier), you may look at microapache http://microapache.kerys.co.uk/